# Add XAML elements inside WEB VIEW in windows phone 8.1

Tags: wpf, xaml

Am developing windows phone app.In web view I load html elements,in which whenever content exceeds web view height there is scroll with  no issues.
My problem is am having xaml elements in the top of web view,which have to scroll  along with web view scroll.

Sample:

```
<ScrollViewer>
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
<RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" >
<StackPanel x:name="xamlelement" Margin="15 20 0 0">
  -------
  -------
  -------
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
<Grid x:Name="testgrid" Grid.Row="1">
<WebView Margin="0 30 0 0"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="msgContent" >
</WebView>
</Grid>
</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

when "msgContent" webview element scrolls I want "xamlelement" stack panel to scroll along with web view

Answer (score 0):

You need to measure the content of the "Html page" and set the height of the web view to the measured height. Then you have to disable the scroll for the web view.

```
msgContent.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```

So that you will have two elements in the natural flow "Your stack panel + web view", inside the scroll view. So it will easily scroll in the way you want.